# Can TypeScript enforce abstract constructor arguments?

Tags: typescript

This function takes a constructor that expects a `string` argument and returns an instance of the constructed value `T`:

```js
function make<T>(ctor: new(value: string) => T): T {
    return new ctor("Hello");
}
```

Now, we'll set up a couple of test classes; one with a default constructor, and one with a constructor that accepts a `string` argument:

```js
class Foo {
}

class Bar {
    constructor(value: string) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is as follows:

```js
const instance: Bar = make(Bar);
```

> "Hello"

However, `Foo` causes some problems...

**Problem 1**

`instance` can be declared as `Foo`, but `make` called with `Bar`:

```js
const instance: Foo = make(Bar);
```

> "Hello"

**Problem 2**

`instance` can be declared as `Bar`, but `make` called with `Foo`. This one is more concerning, because not only is the declaration mismatched with the return type of `make`, but also because `Foo` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `string` argument:

```js
const instance: Bar = make(Foo);
```

Why does TypeScript allow this, and is there a way to enforce the *correct* behaviour?

Example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQBfVrSRgITACcVVozph4A7CAF0IFdhb5CAKANzBAYFMAuaHUIBLKgHMAlCXKyK1CPBC8AdCHjjO3PpIDcpcpkyoAZgyrMR1aAFswAa14AeACoA%20Ns1aCqvAO5aPAJC9GJS0AC8btAukoIuMuSEvLQMhFTQvn4ULOwARAASvCDqeXoYWJQ0tNBidGAWwQTEEbYOvGzN5agA9D0xABa8ELxCA-AMIAAmmfA1AEajAA7wUCLzygCE2Ao1S4TwG7w2AIyCCEitdo6dROVVdND7h8o2AEyCzZFtNxd6QA)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does TypeScript allow this?

The issue you're seeing is due to how TypeScript's type inference system works. It's not that TypeScript is "allowing" mismatches, but rather, it's not able to precisely infer the relationship between the type parameter `T`, your `ctor` function, and the classes `Foo` and `Bar`.

When you invoke `make(Bar)` or `make(Foo)`, TypeScript doesn't check whether the constructors in `Foo` or `Bar` match the type of `ctor (namely new (value: string) => T)`. Instead, it infers the type `T` based on the provided constructor function, which leads to the potential mismatches you're observing.

As for the issue with `Foo` not having a constructor that accepts a string, this is fundamentally a JavaScript issue. JavaScript allows you to call a constructor with any number of arguments regardless of how the function is defined, which TypeScript then inherits. When you try to call `make(Foo)`, JavaScript calls the Foo constructor with `"Hello"`, but as `Foo`'s constructor doesn't take any arguments, it just ignores the provided `"Hello"`.

> is there a way to enforce the correct behaviour?

At present, TypeScript doesn't allow for enforcing a specific constructor signature when using classes. This is because in JavaScript, a class constructor function (which is what you're passing to make) doesn't have any runtime signature; it's just a function that can be called with any number of arguments.

However, there still are some workarounds to establish stronger restrictions.

One solution is to prohibit calling make with classes that have a parameter-less constructor. This could be achieved by creating a `Marker` class with a private field, and extending all classes that can be used with make from Marker:

```
class Marker {
    private __marker!: void; // The private field makes Marker non-constructible
}

interface IConstructable<T extends Marker> {
    new (arg: string): T;
}

function make<T extends Marker>(ctor: IConstructable<T>): T {
    return new ctor("Hello");
}

class Foo extends Marker {
    // TypeScript compiler error here: Property '__marker' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Marker'.
}

class Bar extends Marker {
    constructor(value: string) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}

const instanceBar: Bar = make(Bar); // This compiles fine
const instanceFoo: Foo = make(Foo); // Error
```

Comment: Allowing for the rename from `StringConstructor` (defined by TypeScript itself), `instance1` compiled without issue: 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxQK4JjpQA8AKgHzIDeyAUMo8iBAO7IAUAbnADZ4QAXMhxRQAcwCUwsgG56AXzp0YeEIWCZkAWzgBrCOQodCxYRmy4CRUpWnIyNBkygQweKCGZtkpqBwAiAAkIXl50AMlZOiUAeli0XjgsLAgsOgQklOQAMXR0JyUMrKxkACE4KCcmX0xRa2JuPgFhUQlJapqmBDr0XggAOnDxJv4IKOdGJSL4hwALYFLWYDDkADkAeUce7QAHFYgAGmRk3PyAclKey3w-ZAATdDTmdDAdODAEOeQwOZRXACOeGArnuImA4hAHw8EAydTeoBwcHUEAAjMI8gUALzvAwcTFReh0WZkBZLFa8Wp7A4nEBg1jEPQnUqgSB0iD3OGWZCIsDIpAAJmEFSqON0eJFhKAA

Comment: You're right, I really tried to find a solution, but that is what I found on the edited post friend :/

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has a structural type system, not a nominal one. That means that assignment compatiblity is determined by the structure of types involved (their members) rather than their names.

As far as TypeScript is concerned, Foo and Bar are equivalent types, since they have the same (empty) set of members:

```
const foo = new Foo();
const bar: Bar = foo; // just fine: a Foo has all the properties Bar needs
const foo2: Foo = bar; // just fine: a Bar has all the properties Foo needs
```

So if the compiler is supposed to distinguish these types, they need a different structure. For instance, like this:

```
class Foo {
  age: number;
}

class Bar {
  constructor (public name: string)
}
```

If you make that change, TypeScript will recognise these types as different, and prevent type mixups:

```
const problem1: Foo = make(Bar); // Property 'age' is missing in type 'Bar' but required in type 'Foo'.
const problem2: Bar = make(Foo); // Property 'name' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'
```

Your issue therefore has nothing to do with the enforcement of "abstract constructor arguments". Your make function is correctly typed, and the compiler will check it.

That leaves the question of why you are allowed to call `make(Foo)`. The reason is that `make` passes all arguments `Foo` needs (and one more that Foo doesn't need, but that doesn't cause any issue at runtime, so typescript permits it).

Passing a function which requires less arguments is often useful, for instance here:

```
stringArray.filter(x => x.startsWith(searchTerm));
```

The filter method expects a callback with 3 parameters, but we are allowed to pass a function that declares just 1 parameter. If we couldn't do that, we'd have to write:

```
stringArray.filter((x, index, array) => x.startsWith(searchTerm));
```

which would be needlessly painful ...